# Remove whitespace between dynamically generated html search results for CSS inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am using the mixItUp jQuery API on my website. I was having an issue with spacing on inline-block elements primarily because of the excess whitespace inline-block adds.

Normally I would use a `<!-- -->` to remove the whitespace between the html elements where needed, but I can't seem to do that on account of the html results get generated dynamically. The html code that structures the search results are also in a different "search-results" PHP template file for organization.

```
<div class="container">

   <!-- The three DIVs below are generated with PHP in a different template file -->
   <div class="result 1">Content</div>
   <div class="result 2">Content</div>
   <div class="result 3">Content</div>

</div>
```

So the question is how would I remove the whitespace produced by inline-block on these 3 hypothetical DIV elements?

Please note, I don't want to use any hacky CSS tricks as they always have a support related con (ex. margin-right:-4px, font-size:0, etc).

Thank you!

Comment: what whitespace are you talking about?

Comment: Show the template file that generates to results - thats what you will need to edit

Comment: Browsers ignore whitespace in the HTML code.

Comment: @jeff Not with `inline-block` elements they dont

Comment: You have invalid classes.

Comment: @lxer the tabs and newline chars between the html elements. This is a known `inline-block` bug: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Well, the obvious thing would be not to use inline-blocks. It's not a bug, it's intentional. Try floats.

Comment: can't you just fix this in the PHP script that generates the \n and spaces?

Comment: This is a quintessential problem with layout on page vs. layout in editing.  Those suggesting complicated work-arounds with altering what the server is outputting or changing the display of the elements entirely to solve the problem are discounting the possibility that he may need any of the number of rules which will only apply to inline blocks, such as `vertical-align`, `text-align` or `white-space`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, floating the elements will remove the whitespace (and is the appropriate way to do what you're doing).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback here. I'm guessing there isn't a true solution to something like this other than accommodating the extra space and using @media queries to change the spacing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super easy:

```
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.container > div {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

This option sets the `font-size` to `0` so that the white-space consumes no space.  Then, it resets the `font-size` to the root-level declaration with `font-size: 1rem` for all immediate children divs.

## --OR--

```
<div class="container"><!--

   --><div class="result 1">Content</div><!--
   --><div class="result 2">Content</div><!--
   --><div class="result 3">Content</div><!--

--></div>
```

This is simply adding a comment between the items so that you can preserve your document layout (for editing purposes) while essentially telling the browser to ignore everything in between the tags.

Comment: Let me be clear, for your specific scenario you definitely want the first option.  The second is more for manually input items.

Comment: Hi Josh, doesn't the font-size: 0 have issues on Android or something rather? I thought there was a relatively big incompatibility somewhere with that CSS trick.

Comment: @user3775937 – Nope, not that I'm aware of, at least.  Just tried it out on my Nexus and it works fine.